# Extend JQueryStatic for a JQuery Plugin that has no definition file

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I use the [IFrame Transport Plugin](https://cmlenz.github.io/jquery-iframe-transport/) for JQuery. It introduces a new property `iframe` on the `JQueryAjaxSettings` interface. Unfortunately the plugin has no definition file, which means it throws errors in Intellisense and when compiling the project because I have to use that `iframe` property in my code.

So I created 2 new Interfaces in a separate `d.ts` file to extend JQuery's definition file:

```
interface JQueryIframeTransportStatic extends JQueryStatic {
    ajax(settings: IJQueryIframeTransportAjaxSettings): JQueryXHR;
}

interface IJQueryIframeTransportAjaxSettings extends JQueryAjaxSettings {
    iframe: boolean;
}
```

But this throws the following error when compiling:

> TS2430: Build: Interface 'JQueryStaticIframeTransport' incorrectly extends interface 'JQueryStatic'.

I see that TypeScript may be confused by the new `ajax` function introduced by my interface. But it has a different signature. How else could I extend it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface can be extended like this:

```
interface JQueryStatic {
    ajax(settings: IJQueryIframeTransportAjaxSettings): JQueryXHR;
}

interface IJQueryIframeTransportAjaxSettings extends JQueryAjaxSettings {
    iframe: boolean;
}
```

This just adds the new function declaration, not requiring the `extends` construct. Building on this, you can do it with just one declaration, viz.

```
interface JQueryAjaxSettings {
    iframe: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Your first version worked. The second didn't. But I'm happy :)

Comment: No problem, btw, I did try the second version too and it worked for me